# Applying MVT to function that has limit of its derivative given when $x\to\infty$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow R$ be differentiable on $(0,\infty)$ and assume that $f'(x)\rightarrow b$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$.

(a) Show that for any $h>0$, we have $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=b$.

(b) Show that if $f(x)\rightarrow a$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$, then $b=0$.

(c) Show that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}=b$.

Note: this is exercise 6.2.16 from "Introduction to Real Analysis" by Bartle & Sherbert, that I'm using for self-study.  Part (a) is an easy one, but am stuck with parts (b) and (c).  My solution to part (a) would be as follows:

By definition, $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f'(x)=b$ means that for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $K(\epsilon)$ such that if $x>K$, then $|f'(x)-b|<\epsilon$. Now, for given $h>0$, it is that $x+h>K$ too, and by MVT there exists $c$ such that $x<c<x+h$ and $f'(c)=\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$. As $c>K$, then $\lvert f'(c)-b \rvert <\epsilon$ too, and thus $\left|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}-b\right|<\epsilon$ for all $x>K$; which, by definition, means that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=b$.

Another note: Bartle & Sherbert book has no solutions for all exercises, but for many of them there exist publicly available solutions. For this one, however, the only solution available is [here.](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110830060846AABkg0x)  However, arguments provided there to prove parts (b) and (c) just don't seem rigorous enough to me.

Comment: What are your ideas? Obviously you have a hint that you gave in the title. Apply it!

Comment: What does $f'(x)\to b$ mean precisely? Then use this and the MVT on a)

Comment: Do b) first, this is very easy.

Comment: If only this problem was from section 6.3 ... Regardless, see [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298832/if-lim-x-to-infty-fx-l-then-lim-x-to-infty-frac-fxx/298848) (there may be an easier answer; my answer in the linked post is just Bartle and Sherbert's proof of  one version of l'Hôpital's rule).

Comment: Thanks David, that solved the (c) part. Apologies to other commenters that I provided my approach in solving part (a) only after posting the message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f'(x) = L$, then $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac {f(x)}{x} = L$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298832/if-lim-x-to-infty-fx-l-then-lim-x-to-infty-frac-fxx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (b). Put $h=1$ in (a), you have:
$$
b = \lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x+1)-f(x) = a - a = 0.
$$

For (c) you have to reproduce the proof of l'Hopital theorem... I don't see any simplification.