# Show that $\liminf\limits_{x\to \infty}|f'(x)|=0$ if $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}f(x)/x=0$ and $f$ is differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, limsup-and-liminf

Let $f$ be a differentiable Function on $(0,\infty)$ such that $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac {f(x)}{x}$=0.

I have to show that $\liminf_{x\to \infty}|f'(x)|=0$.

I had thought to apply the mean value theorem for the function $g(x)= \frac {f(x)}{x}$ over the interval $(x,2x)$ so that
$$
\frac{\frac {f(2x)}{2x}-\frac {f(x)}{x}}{x}=g'(c)=\frac{cf'(c)-f(c)}{c^2}
$$
for $c\in (x,2x)$. Then 
$$
\frac {f(2x)-2f(x)}{2}=\frac{cf'(c)-f(c)}{c^2}=\frac {f'(c)}{c}-\frac {f(c)}{c^2}
$$
How to proceed further I have no idea. Is my way is right? Or do I have to choose another way? Any help will be appreciated

Comment: "How to Proceed Further" I am not sure what it is exactly you think you "proceeded" with so far, but anyway... What happens if $$\liminf|f'(x)|\geqslant\epsilon$$ for some positive $\epsilon$? This has some easy, rather drastic, consequences on $f'$, hence on $f$. Please state the ones you can think about. (Oh, and by the way, are you sure the hypothesis is that $f$ is differentiable, or that $f$ is continuously differentiable?)

Comment: First of all Sorry Sir I have not such intention to Write .  As per your suggestion,I think  if lim inf of that that derivative is positive then that function must goes to Infinity. because function is increasing .

Comment: @Did What would you want continuous derivatives for?

Comment: Function is given to differentible on that interval .Sir what will happen if this function is continously differentible ?

Comment: It seems a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298832/if-lim-x-to-infty-fx-l-then-lim-x-to-infty-frac-fxx

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen OK, not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Then there exists $M_\epsilon>0$ such that $\left|\frac{f(x)}{x}\right|<\frac\epsilon3$ for all $x>M_\epsilon$.
So for such $x$, the Mean Value Theorem tells us that there exists $\xi\in(x,2x)$ such that
$$x|f'(\xi)|=|f(2x)-f(x)|\le|f(2x)|+|f(x)|<\frac\epsilon3\cdot 2 x+\frac\epsilon3\cdot  x=\epsilon x.$$
Therefore $|f'(\xi)|<\epsilon$ for some $\xi \in(x,2x)$ whenever $x>M_\epsilon$. This makes $\liminf|f'(x)|\le \epsilon$. As this holds for all $\epsilon>0$, we get $\liminf |f'(x)|=0$.